# Impersonating a specific domain user from the internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

We have a vendor app that uses windows authentication to pass windows credentials from their MVC app to a web browser control that is pointed at a internal site.  This provides a SSO-like experience from the app to the IIS session.

We want to publish the IIS site on the internet and the external/non-domain user must be automatically authenticated in our domain out on the internet.  We don't want to put a domain controller in the DMZ.  The vendor app is a compiled c#.net site.  They will log into our portal site with a simple username and password.  This set will be the same for an actual AD user.  We want to turn their simple login into a windows authenticated "session" so that when we redirect them to the vendor app, their app will see that they are (somehow) an authenticated windows authentication user and simply pass them on through.  (Providing them with a SSO-like experience).

This works if you are on our network and logged into the domain, but these will be non-domain users out on the internet.

Comment: Their site has windows authentication.  We've tried creating one with it turned off.  We've tried putting the impersonate tag in the config, but each user has their own settings.  We need something like impersonate on the fly?  We've tried cookies that get passed into their app (we write, they read).  This works but not for windows auth mode.

Comment: Are you saying that the users do not exist in the Windows domain, but you would like to generate a Windows security context for them.. so they can logon to Windows auth protected apps?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  They actually are in the active directory, but they are not logging into it.  We are bouncing their credentials off AD to see if that username/password combination is valid.  If it is, then they get access.  In this new process, we want them to actually have a windows session/context based on their username/password because, the new vendor app uses windows auth to get in.  But, we are unsure how to convert the one login into a valid windows auth session out on the internet.  The vendor app will be in an iframe if that makes any difference.